# Jersey non-annotated Provider

Tags: java, spring, jersey

I'm using Jersey with Spring for a REST API and I wrote a provider to modify JSON serialization. The problem is that when I use the `@Component` annotation, the provider's callback method is called for other servlets. When I remove the `@Component` annotation, it doesn't get called at all.

Here is the provider:

```
@Component
@Provider

public class ObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

public ObjectMapperProvider() {
}

@Override
public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
     ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
     SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("SimpleModule", new org.codehaus.jackson.Version(1, 0, 0, null));
     module.addSerializer(BigInteger.class, new ToStringSerializer());
     objectMapper.registerModule(module);
     return objectMapper;   
}
}
```

I tried to use the Jersey configuration in the web.xml, but that didn't help either.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, that wasn't my problem. The provider was called for the right servlet.
 My application didn't work because I had an XmlAdapter for Map, and with my ObjectMapperProvider, the json response was different.
Here is my updated ObjectMapperProvider  class:

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {


     @Context
     UriInfo uriInfo;

    public ObjectMapperProvider() {
    }


    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
         ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
         SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("SimpleModule", new org.codehaus.jackson.Version(1, 0, 0, null));
         module.addSerializer(BigInteger.class, new ToStringSerializer());
         objectMapper = objectMapper.configure(Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, false).configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, false)
                 .configure(Feature.WRAP_EXCEPTIONS, true).configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true).configure(Feature.WRITE_EMPTY_JSON_ARRAYS, false);
         final AnnotationIntrospector introspector = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector();
         objectMapper.getDeserializationConfig().setAnnotationIntrospector(introspector); // using a deprecated API that works. Non-deprecated API doesn't work...
         objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().setAnnotationIntrospector(introspector);
         objectMapper.registerModule(module);
         return objectMapper;   
    }

}
```

Once I configured my Object wrapper to use JAXB annotations, everything worked as expected. I got the idea on how to do that from the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517189/spring-mvc-and-jackson-mapping-do-not-return-the-root-element-in-json)