# Jackson - Wrapping a list of objects with root object

Tags: java, jackson, object-object-mapping, mongo-jackson-mapper

My Controller returns a list of MyObj objects (using @ResponseBody)

```
public MyObj 
{
   int a;
   int b;
}
```

The return JSON looks like this:

```
[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":2,"b":2}]
```

I would like to wrap this JSON so it will return something like:

```
{ "data": [{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":2,"b":2}]}
```

From what i read i need to enable SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE or (?) use
@JsonRootName("data") on top of my controller.

Also tried the @XmlRootElement, nothing seems to work.
Any idea what is the right way to wrap the list of objects with a root name?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? I figured out a round about way by creating a map of lists, and then letting ObjectMapper do it's thing, but that isn't so elegant. I am thinking there's a better way to do this. Did you figure it out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use class name as root key for JSON Jackson serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435527/use-class-name-as-root-key-for-json-jackson-serialization)

Answer (score 11):

It sounds like you're talking about putting `@JsonRootName` on the list rather than the object, which won't accomplish what you're trying to do.

If you would like to use `@JsonRootName` you'll want to enable `SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE` like you mentioned above and add the annotation to the class:

```
@JsonRootName("data")
public MyObj {
    int a;
    int b;
}
```

This will wrap the objects themselves, *not* the list:

```
{
    "listName": [
        {
            "data": {"a":1, "b":2}
        },
        {
            "data": {"a":2, "b":2}
        }
    ]
}
```

If you want to wrap the list in an object, perhaps creating a generic object wrapper is the best solution.  This can be accomplished with a class like this:

```
public final class JsonObjectWrapper {
    private JsonObjectWrapper() {}

    public static <E> Map<String, E> withLabel(String label, E wrappedObject) {
        return Collections.singletonMap(label, wrappedObject);
    }
}
```

Then before you send your list back with the response, just wrap it in `JsonObjectWrapper.withLabel("data", list)` and Jackson takes care of the rest.

Comment: Perhaps Collections.singletonMap(label, wrappedObject) would be more efficient and consise?

Comment: Great suggestion @charlie_pl! Updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
    List<MyObj> myList;
    
    ObjectWriter ow = mapper.writer()
            .with(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE)
            .withRootName("data");
    
    System.out.println(ow.writeValueAsString(myList));
```