# JACKSON, JSON : List Titles

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I'm using `Jackson` lib to generate `Json`files.

after creating the bean class,

Class ActiveOrderResponse

```
public class ActiveOrderResponse implements IWsResponse {

    @JsonProperty("error")
    public String errorMsg;

    @JsonProperty("errorDsc")
    public String errorDesc = "";

    @JsonProperty("Orders")
    public ArrayList<ActiveOrder> orders = new ArrayList<ActiveOrder>();
}
```

Class ActiveOrder

```
public class ActiveOrder {

    @JsonProperty("OrderNo")
    private String orderNo;

    @JsonProperty("Status")
    private String status;

    @JsonProperty("Description")
    private String description = "";
}
```

i have this `Json` in the Result :

```
{"error":"000",
"errorDsc":"",
"Orders":[
{"OrderNo":"Order_1",
"Status":"NOT_EXISTS",
"Description":""},
{"OrderNo":"Order_2",
"Status":"COMPLETED",
"Description":""},
{"OrderNo":"Order_3",
"Status":"CREATED",
"Description":""},
{"OrderNo":"Order_4",
"Status":"NOT_IMPORTED",
"Description":""}]
}
```

But i went the Json be like this (a title **"Order"** in the beginning of every Order List):

```
{"error":"000",
"errorDsc":"",
"Orders":[
"Order" : {"OrderNo":"Order_1",
"Status":"NOT_EXISTS",
"Description":""},
"Order" : {"OrderNo":"Order_2",
"Status":"COMPLETED",
"Description":""},
"Order" : {"OrderNo":"Order_3",
"Status":"CREATED",
"Description":""},
"Order" : {"OrderNo":"Order_4",
"Status":"NOT_IMPORTED",
"Description":""}]
}
```

Comment: Can you show the class `ActiveOrder` please?

Comment: Here is an example similar to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435527/use-class-name-as-root-key-for-json-jackson-serialization

Comment: thanks @Wakachopo i find the solution in your taged question.

Comment: @JsonTypeInfo(include=As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use=Id.NAME)

Answer (score 0):

My environment, if problem not solved , show me the code with ObjectMapper:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.6</version>
</dependency>


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ActiveOrderResponse activeOrderResponse = new ActiveOrderResponse();
    activeOrderResponse.orders = new ArrayList<ActiveOrder>();
    activeOrderResponse.orders.add(new ActiveOrder());
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    om.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
    om.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, true);
    String json = om.writeValueAsString(activeOrderResponse);
    System.out.println(json);
}


{
    "error" : null,
        "errorDsc" : "",
        "Orders" : [ {
    "OrderNo" : null,
            "Status" : null,
            "Description" : ""
} ]
}
```