# Can't generate json with named root element

Tags: java, json, rest, maven, jackson

I have a some code with next layers:

```
@JsonRootName("users")
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private Integer id;
   @Column(name = "first_name")
   private String firstName;
   @Column(name = "last_name")
   private String lastName;
   @Column(name = "age")
   private Integer age;
   @Column(name = "code")
   private Integer code;

   public Integer getId() {
      return id;
   }

   public void setId(Integer id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
   }

   public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
   }

   public String getLastName() {
      return lastName;
   }

   public void setLastName(String lastName) {
      this.lastName = lastName;
   }

   public Integer getAge() {
      return age;
   }

   public void setAge(Integer age) {
      this.age = age;
   }

   public Integer getCode() {
      return code;
   }

   public void setCode(Integer code) {
      this.code = code;
   }
}

public class UsersDao {
   @Autowired
   public SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   public Session session() {
      return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
   }

   public List<User> findAll(){
      Query<User> query = session().createQuery("from User", User.class);
      return query.list();
   }
}

public class UsersService {
   @Autowired
   public UsersDao usersDao;

   @Transactional(readOnly = true)
   public List<User> findAllUsers(){
      return usersDao.findAll();
   }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UsersController {
   @Autowired
   UsersService usersService;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/all", produces = {"application/json"})
   @ResponseBody
   public List<User> getAllUsers() {
      return usersService.findAllUsers();
   }
}
```

When I try a get request localhost:8080/testreactproject/users/all

```
[{"id":1,"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","age":28,"code":916},{"id":2,"firstName":"Jane","lastName":"Doe","age":27,"code":985}]
```

But I want to get next json with the root element

```
{"users":[{"id":1,"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","age":28,"code":916},{"id":2,"firstName":"Jane","lastName":"Doe","age":27,"code":985}]}
```

This one of dependecy into my pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.10</version>
</dependency>
```

I know that I should create instance of ObjectMapper class and then configure this instance next way

```
mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true)
```

I tried to add this code in controller-class (method getAllUsers) but it doesn't work for me.
What do I do wrong?

Comment: You should explain "it doesn't work for me" means.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use class name as root key for JSON Jackson serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435527/use-class-name-as-root-key-for-json-jackson-serialization)

Comment: Okay, I rephrase: "It doesn't work".

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved. I created class wrapper for class User (entity layer) and bind root element for wrapper. So I got a correct json object.
It is look like:

```
@JsonRootName(value = "users")
public class UsersWrapper {
   private List<User> users;

   public List<User> getUsers() {
      return users;
   }

   public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
      this.users = users;
   }
}
```