# Adding the name of the class to the json

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

I'm new to json and objectMapper in Java, and I have a class with two fields, and I want to create json of this class, but I only get using the mapper the attributes. How can I do this?

```
public class Car{
   String a;
   String b;
```

}

```
ObjectMapper mapper;
String car = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Car(a, b));
```

the json:

```
"{a: a, b: b}"
```

what I want: `{Car: { a: a, b: b } }`

Comment: Note that libraries like Jackson support something like this. Why exactly do you want the class in the json? What should happen if you'd have 2 or more cars? Should it be `[{"Car":{...}},{"Car":{...}}, ...]`?

Comment: @Thomas you are right. [Here is a common SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435527/use-class-name-as-root-key-for-json-jackson-serialization).

Answer (score 2):

By using JACKSON, you can achieve this by using `JsonRootName` annotation.

You can add it above your class with the value you want it to be your JSON root element.
In your case, you should do the following:

```
@JsonRootName(value = "car")
@JsonTypeInfo(include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT ,use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
public class Car{
...
}
```

As you can see, we also added the `JsonTypeInfo` annotation which is necessary because it indicate which type of wrapping should be used.

Also you can get rid of `@JsonRootName(value = "Car")` and only use `@JsonTypeInfo(include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT ,use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)` if you want the root field to have the same value as the class name.